# Spectral decomposition of Hessian

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am running into issues when attempting to shift a Hessian to be positive definite for an optimization problem in Matlab. An example of my problem is:

`H=[1 2 2; 
    2 3 2;
    1 3 1];
[V,D]=eig(H);`

While `H*V-V*D`, as it should, essentially equals zero:

`V*D*V'` does not provide the original H matrix

Comment: V' is the notation for a transposed version of V. If you want the inverse, use inv(V). V*inv(V) will give you the identity matrix

Comment: This was an error on my part. I do get the correct value when using inverse. Not sure why the transpose is shown in my lecture slides. I only assumed that this was possibly a unique case for an eigenvector matrix and its corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually tried to run your code:

```
H = [
  1 2 2; 
  2 3 2;
  1 3 1
];

[V,D] = eig(H);

test = norm(H*V-V*D,inf) / norm(V*D,inf);
```

and I'm seeing no obvious problems with the example you posted. The eigenvalues and vectors that I get satisfy their defining equation with high accuracy:

```
test = 7.57596318689868e-16
```

On the top of that, as @kpg987 pointed out, you have to use the inverse of V, not the transposed version of V. And if you perform the following test:

```
test = V * D * inv(V);
```

You will obtain your original hessian (or something very very close to it).

Comment: You both are correct. As I stated in response to @kpg987, I was working off of an incorrect expectation. Thanks